# read google spreadsheet for changes in data

Tags: javascript, google-docs-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-drive-api

Want to read a google drive spreadsheet and have eventlistener for any changes on my webapp . 
Thus far I have been able to authorize my app in javascript to read the list of files in my directory.

Took the id from this list to GET the spreadsheet I need, failing to GET this file.

```
  function printFile(fileId) {
      var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
        'fileId': fileId
      });
      request.execute(function(resp) {
        console.log('Title: ' + resp.title);
        console.log('Description: ' + resp.description);
        console.log('MIME type: ' + resp.mimeType);
      });
    }

  /**
   * Retrieve a list of File resources.
   *
   * @param {Function} callback Function to call when the request is complete.
   */
  function retrieveAllFiles(callback) {
    var retrievePageOfFiles = function(request, result) {
      request.execute(function(resp) {
        var i=0;
        result = result.concat(resp.items);
        var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
        for(i=0;i<resp.items.length;i++){
            console.log(resp.items[i])
            if (resp.items[i].id == "XxxxxxXxxx"){
                printFile(resp.items[i].id);
                break;
            }
        }
      });
    }
    var initialRequest = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/drive/v2/files',
        'method': 'GET',
        'params': {'maxResults': '5'}
        });
    retrievePageOfFiles(initialRequest, []);
  }
```

**issue definitely here:**

```
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    'fileId': fileId
  });
```

I am copying google drive api example for GET!!! **My code stops execution. Doesn't go beyond this.**

Answer (score 0):

Part 1:
Solution by changing the request call:

```
var request1 = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/drive/v2/files/'+fileId,
    'method': 'GET',
});
```